# Feature importance and number of trees in random forest

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I am working with random forest binary classifier. To select the features I am using mean decrease impurity and mean decrease accuracy.

Does the number of estimators (number of trees) matter for feature importance in Random forest? I mean, does it principally effect the set of selected features?

Comment: Yes. The contributions are summed over trees.

Comment: Dear  Michael M, yes, contributions are summed, but does it effect the relative importance between features, i.e. the  proportions?

Comment: The trees are different, thus yes.